# Warning messages during the training of my classification model using Caret and xgboost

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, xgboost

I am using `Caret` in `R` to run the `xgboost` algorithm for a machine learning classification problem.

After running the following `R` codes, I am getting the warning messages (shown below):

```
cl <- makeCluster(10, type = "SOCK")

registerDoSNOW(cl)

caret.cv <- train(market ~ ., 
                  data = mydata.train,
                  method = "xgbTree",
                  tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                  trControl = train.control)


Warning messages:
1: closing unused connection 12 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
2: closing unused connection 11 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
3: closing unused connection 10 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
4: closing unused connection 9 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
5: closing unused connection 8 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
6: closing unused connection 7 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
7: closing unused connection 6 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
8: closing unused connection 5 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
9: closing unused connection 4 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916) 
10: closing unused connection 3 (<-John-laptop.mycompany.local:11916)
```

Can I ignore them and proceed on with the analysis or is something wrong behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment...

When you started your cluster, R made a connection to each process. The warning messages are simply the connections being automatically closed.

It would be more elegant to stop your cluster and close them explicitly, but if you are not having any problems you could realistically ignore it.

Something like `stopCluster(cl)` (depends on which libraries you have loaded) will stop the cluster but you will sometimes still get errors about unused connections - this is unlikely to be a real issue as you are not close to the connections limit.

Note that 10 threads is probably excessive on a laptop - try `detectCores()` from the `parallel` package, to get the number of processors, and use that.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks.